# Where should I put serialized objects in a Java program?

Tags: java, json, serialization, project-organization

Hello you wonderful people,

All is not right with the world! I am trying to use JSON to persist objects in a java program. I don't use java often, and I'm using JSON to serialize my obejcts because I want other programs written in other languages to be able to adopt these serialized objects as well. My problem is that I can't figure out the correct place to put my JSON files. Initially I though that I should put them in a resources folder, but it seems that it is not possible to write files to resource folders on the fly. I could of course put the files in a folder that is external to my project, but that would kind of bug me ... a lot.

It's these kinds of silly nuances that have always turned me off to java.
any comments/suggestions/cold, heartless criticisms would be welcome.

thanks.

Comment: Are these JSON files generated by your program at run time or are they resources used to build the program? How are they supposed to be used by other programs? Are they meant to be re-read by the program that generated them?

Comment: How is this problem, in Java, different from any other environment? You have to chose any kind of storage medium and put your JSON data there, that's all. A database, a storage web service, an FTP server, a folder in a harddisk, etc.

Comment: @TedHopp the JSON files contain calibration data for physical sensors. The data is used when I build my program, but the calibrations can change while the program runs. I do not need to re-read the files, but I do need to be able to update them. I have other programs that use this sensor and I want to be able to share new calibrations between them (by copying the files).

Comment: @BrunoReis I guess I just meant that other languages don't have nice, appealing resource folders ... that you can't write to at run time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I interpret your question something like this: You want to generate JSON files at runtime and write them to your `resources` folder.

This is not how it is supposed to work – the `resources` folder is used to contain non-sourcecode files that are used by the program but are included in the distribution, like a Spring application context XML file.

If you want to exchange data with other programs (possibly written in other languages) you should probably use a common exchange directory outside of your program's source tree.

Comment: thanks. When you put it that way it does sound like the right way to do it.